# How to convert HTML to Java (Android)?

Tags: android, html, upload

I have 3 files to upload from my android tablet and I will like to convert the below HTML. Please give me examples for 3 files uploaded from android to server.

```
 Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=AaB03x

 --AaB03x
 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="submit-name"

 --AaB03x
 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files"
 Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=BbC04y

 --BbC04y
 Content-Disposition: file; name="uploadLogo"; filename="file1.jpg"
 Content-Type: image/gif
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary


 --BbC04y
 Content-Disposition: file; name="uploadImage"; filename="file2.gif"
 Content-Type: image/gif
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
```

**Above code should be converted to this java code:**

```
   public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {
    String upLoadServerUri = urlModifProfil;
    String fileName = sourceFileUri;

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;  
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 
    File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri); 
    if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
     Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File Does not exist");
     return 0;
    }
        try { // open a URL connection to the Servlet
         FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
         URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);
         conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
         conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
         conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
         conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
         conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
         conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
         conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
         conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
         conn.setRequestProperty("uploadLogo", fileName); 
         dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

         dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
         dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadLogo\";filename=\""+ fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
         dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

         bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); // create a buffer of  maximum size

         bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
         buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

         // read file and write it into form...
         bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

         while (bytesRead > 0) {
           dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
           bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
           bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
           bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);               
          }

         // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
         dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
         dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

         // Responses from the server (code and message)
         serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
         String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

         Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : " + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);
         if(serverResponseCode == 200){
             runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                      editlogo.setText("File Upload Completed.");
                      Toast.makeText(MainClient.this, "File Upload Complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
              });                
         }    

         //close the streams //
         fileInputStream.close();
         dos.flush();
         dos.close();

    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {  
        dialog.dismiss();  
        ex.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(MainClient.this, "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);  
    } catch (Exception e) {
        dialog.dismiss();  
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(MainClient.this, "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), e);  
    }
```

This Java code is for one uploaded file only and I will like  to do this for 2 or 3 uploaded files.

Any help is greatly appreciated ! Thank you !

Comment: Question is still unclear. Explain properly what is your purpose and what do you want to do here ?

Comment: @salama007: is that java code is not working , i was not able to understand your pblm, are you facing any crash or any exception,what was your problem with the java code?

Comment: @Sankar Ganesh: this java code uploade juste one picture but i need 2 or 3 picture